Should I reinforce my crumbling wall or replace it?
I just bought an apartment, and pieces of walls are  cracking and falling off. I don't understand how, or why, but if I can break the falling pieces of my wall with my hand, then something is obviously wrong. Do I just reinforce it? If yes, then how? If I have to tear it down, then how do I do that? And what should I do after that?
I'd add pictures but I don't understand how to do it here.
All of my walls are covered in this plaster. It breaks wherever I touch it. My question is more about whether I should replace the plaster here, or remove it.


Welcome to DIY.SE! Could you please clarify this: "I just brought an apartment" I assume that should be "bought" as in "purchased" not "brought" as in "carried  along with". Did you buy the apartment or are you renting it? Purchase vs rent decides who should fix this: you or the landlord.

Yes, I mean purchased.

The bits falling off appear to just be plaster, not the actual brick from the wall, so it's doubtful there is any structural issue to worry about.
Given how new that uPVC frame (door/window?) looks, it's likely the plaster was damaged when that frame was installed. Either mechanically when the old frame was removed, or possibly even by the expanding foam behind it (its amazing how much force that stuff can exert!).
Any bits that are loose should be removed - particularly if you can just pull them off without force. Given it doesn't appear to be a massive area, the holes left behind can likely just be patched with either fresh base coat plaster, or some pre-mixed deep-hole filler, then smoothed off and repainted.

Just going off of the pictures, the end blocks (the missing block, and the floating one above) are not laid in bond. Any movement or shock (I.E. next to door jam, any settling, or being on a corner that can be hit moving furniture etc.) could knock them loose.
If it is an exterior foundation wall, depending on the type of paint used, it potentially could be trapping moisture in preventing the block from "breathing" causing the mortar to fail
Deciding to repair or replace depends on how large of an area is effected. In my opinion, if it is just the area pictured, I would chip off the block above the missing block, Re-lay the blocks, once the block are set, I would apply wire lath to the block areas (assuming the paint used is breathable masonry paint, if not you would want to remove paint first) then apply scratch coat, brown coat, and finish coat. The wire lath will prevent the cracking at mortar joints.

So I need to strip it to the bricks everywhere, in the whole room?

No, only where there is loose surface material.  The issue , (according to you), is by the window. The window appears to have been recently replaced.  The issue appears to be related to the new window install and not a defect of the total wall.  This is an example of "If it ain't broke, don't fix it"
